# Keyboard isn't showing on IOS emulator in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I don't know why only on IOS emulator keyboard is not showing But on android it's working fine. I am trying to take user input for authentication and sending the data to the real-time database firebase.

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import Input from "../../components/UI/Input";
import Card from "../../components/UI/Card";
import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";
import * as authActions from "../../store/actions/Auth";

const FORM_INPUT_UPDATE = "FORM_INPUT_UPDATE";

const formReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === FORM_INPUT_UPDATE) {
    const updatedValues = {
      ...state.inputValues,
      [action.input]: action.value,
    };
    const updatedValidities = {
      ...state.inputValidities,
      [action.input]: action.isValid,
    };
    let updatedIsFormValid = true;
    for (const key in updatedIsFormValid) {
      updatedIsFormValid = updatedIsFormValid && updatedValidities[key];
    }
    return {
      formIsValid: updatedIsFormValid,
      inputValidities: updatedValidities,
      inputValues: updatedValues,
    };
  }
  return state;
};

const AuthenticationScreen = (props) => {
  const [Isloading, setIsloading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [IsSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [formState, dispatchFormState] = useReducer(formReducer, {
    inputValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    inputValidities: {
      email: false,
      password: false,
    },
    formIsValid: false,
  });

  const authHandler = async () => {
    let action;
    if (IsSignup) {
      action = authActions.signup(
        formState.inputValues.email,
        formState.inputValues.password
      );
    } else {
      action = authActions.login(
        formState.inputValues.email,
        formState.inputValues.password
      );
    }
    setError(null);
    setIsloading(true);
    try {
      await dispatch(action);
      props.navigation.navigate("Shop");
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
      setIsloading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      Alert.alert("An error occurred ", error, [{ text: "Okay" }]);
    }
  }, [error]);

  const inputChangeHandler = useCallback(
    (inputIdentifier, inputValues, inputValidities) => {
      dispatchFormState({
        type: FORM_INPUT_UPDATE,
        value: inputValues,
        isValid: inputValidities,
        input: inputIdentifier,
      });
    },
    [dispatchFormState]
  );
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behaviour="padding"
      keyboardVerticalOffset={50}
      style={styles.screen}
    >
      <Card style={styles.auth}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Input
            id="email"
            label="E-mail"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            required
            email
            autoCapitalize="none"
            warningText="Please enter valid Email Address"
            onInputChange={inputChangeHandler}
            intialValue=""
          />
          <Input
            id="password"
            label="Password"
            keyboardType="default"
            secureTextEntry
            required
            minLength={5}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            warningText="Please enter valid Password"
            onInputChange={inputChangeHandler}
            intialValue=""
          />
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              {Isloading ? (
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Colors.primary} />
              ) : (
                <Button
                  title={IsSignup ? "Sign up" : "Login"}
                  color={Colors.primary}
                  onPress={authHandler}
                />
              )}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Button
                title={`Switch to ${IsSignup ? "Login" : "Sign Up"}`}
                color={Colors.secondary}
                onPress={() => {
                  setIsSignup((prevState) => !prevState);
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </Card>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

AuthenticationScreen.navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: "Authenticate",
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  auth: {
    width: "80%",
    maxWidth: 400,
    maxWidth: 400,
    padding: 20,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  button: {
    margin: 5,
  },
});

export default AuthenticationScreen;
```

I can only be able to type email and password with my laptop keyboard and I have tried clicking on both fields to check whether the keyboard in the IOS emulator popup or not.

The keyboard is working fine on the android emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator detects that you have an external keyboard available and thus doesn't show the software keyboard. You can disable this behaviour using `I/O -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard`. Or you can `Command + K` to toggle the Software Keyboard manually.

Comment: Oh. Okay, I didn't know about this. I thought the ios simulator has some issues. Thanks.

Comment: On flutter the same problem with ios simulator but `cmd + k` fixed it

Comment: In android there is a command but I dont remember it, do you remember about it?